# How to clear the console automatically when R start?

Tags: r

I added some packages in the `defaultPackages` of `Rprofile.site` file using `.First` function, however, there are some warning messages during the R starting, I wonder how to clear the console automatically or suppress these messages when R start. I added `cat("\014")`, but it doesn't work. I know `Ctrl+L` could be used to clear the console after R start.

```
.First <- function(){
options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"),"tidyverse","pacman"))
cat("\014")
}
```

The main messages are from `tidyverse` package.

```
- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
√ ggplot2 3.2.0     √ purrr   0.3.2
√ tibble  2.1.3     √ dplyr   0.8.3
√ tidyr   0.8.3     √ stringr 1.4.0
√ readr   1.3.1     √ forcats 0.4.0
-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ 
tidyverse_conflicts() --
x lubridate::as.difftime() masks base::as.difftime()
x lubridate::date()        masks base::date()
x dplyr::filter()          masks stats::filter()
x lubridate::intersect()   masks base::intersect()
x dplyr::lag()             masks stats::lag()
x lubridate::setdiff()     masks base::setdiff()
x lubridate::union()       masks base::union()
```

Comment: Perhaps `?suppressPackageStartupMessages`.

Comment: when I added `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))'  in `.First`,  other messages disappear except the messages from `lubridate`: `The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date`

Comment: @ jay.sf, this works for my another computer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the following command:

```
cat("\033[2J\033[0;0H")
```

This works for some working environments / terminals. For example, it works for my R standalone running in a terminal, but not in rstudio.

The following works in rstudio, though:

```
cat("\f")
```

(I just saw that this does not work for you  – it is the same as `cat("\014")`. So maybe the first one does).

Comment: All these functions are invalid in both R and Rstudio when I added these to Rprofile.site in `D:\R\R-3.6.1\etc`

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid"? `cat()` is a base R function, so definitely not invalid, and all the above does is to send a bunch of characters to the terminal. It depends on the terminal what to do about them.

Comment: The messages still appear when R or Rstudio start.

Comment: After R or Rstudio start, typing `cat("\014")` could clear the console. I would like to clear the console during R starting, and need not type `cat("\014")` to clear the console.

Comment: OK, I don't use rstudio, so I wouldn't know, sorry! Works on my terminal, though. Also: not "invalid", but "does not work as intended" ;-)